# How do I create different plots from same data frame using the loop function?

Tags: r, loops

I am supposed to create these plots for my course, but I'm very confused with using the looping function. I added an image of my dataframe and the plot I was asked to create. Does anyone know how I can get started?

[image]

[image]

I named my dataframe 'gutan' and I tried to do this so that I can loop through the dataframe:

```
gutan
gd    <- gutan[ , i]
```

Here I tried to just see how it would work if I looped through it, but it did not work because I'm not sure how I can code for it to use one column as x and the other as y on the plot

```
i = 1
for (i in 3:8) {          

plot(gd) }
```

Comment: You can select the columns by ```data[, i:j]```, for example, where i and j are the indexes

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg